# Question about Dual Boot/Wubi

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

Possible to use Wubi with windows 10? Really need easy to install/uninstall way to get any distro of Linux on my computer, dual boot uninstalling seems like a hassle.
~Ciao!

~I NEED A WAY TO INSTALL AND EASILY UNINSTALL, WITHIN 5-10 MINUTES, MAKING A RECOVERY DISK WOULD BE OKAY BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW LONG IT TAKES AND/OR DATA WIPES, ETC~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi is [no longer supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28software%29) unfortunately. The key take away from that Wikipedia article is this:

> Wubi (Windows-based Ubuntu Installer) was an official Windows-based free software installer for Ubuntu, from 2008 until 2015,[2] which allowed the installation of Ubuntu to a single file within an existing Windows partition.

Dual-booting is actually really fairly simple these days. Dual booting is, indeed, your only realistic option. Because each situation may be a little different, I won't expand on it at this time - unless you've a specific question. Instead, I'll refer you to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) where you can get more information.

I don't normally like to link to sites and not include any additional information, but that's the official Ubuntu site and is unlikely to change and is likely to be updated as new information is available.

Instead, let me just make sure to do the following - don't skip anything:

- Backup your data.
- Read the instructions carefully before doing anything.
- Read the instructions a second time *and* ask specific questions if you need help.
- Follow the instructions carefully and know what you're doing before you do it.
- The reason you want to try Linux is because you want something different. This means learning something new. Do not expect it to be the same and do not expect it to be easy (though it really is, just be patient with yourself).
- Be patient with yourself - go slow.
- If you make mistakes then don't worry, you backed up your data in Step 1.
- Before you even try to restore data, if you do make a mistake, it's probably a small and easy to fix problem.
- There's an excellent community online who will help you if you help us to help you and you're willing to put some work into it.

So, my suggestion, burn an ISO to DVD or use `unetbootin` to make a USB thumbdrive to boot to. If you make a USB drive then make sure you format the disk with `FAT32` to ensure that it boots. Give Linux a try in a Live OS situation, be patient, and see if you *actually* want to make the switch or go through with the dual boot process. There are a lot of choices and one of them might be the right choice for you. This will also be a good indicator of the compatibility of your hardware. While you're booted to the Live USB/DVD disk, you needn't worry about it doing anything to your Windows install. You can learn, use, and even install software. (By default, it will sit in RAM unless you've specifically set aside space with `unetbootin` to retain persistent data.)

[Here](http://unetbootin.github.io) is a link to `unetbootin` and it's self-evident with its use. There's a version for Windows, OS X, and Linux. You'll be wanting the Linux version. You can have it download ISOs for you or you can download the ISO yourself and then have it use the downloaded file to make the disk.

Comment: So I have unetbootin and a 64bit ubuntu disk. The thing I'm worried about isn't installing, it's uninstalling. If and when I need to uninstall ubuntu, I don't have a windows install disk to work with, because this was a windows 10 based laptop. Also, what safeboot options should I change if any?

Comment: Because about 2 years ago, I had an old laptop to install whatever I want linux-wise on it. Even though I'm 12, I still know a bit x) but what I am worried about is uninstallation, because I can't just delete the partition in windows. @KGIII

Comment: Windows has an option to make a restore disk. Your laptop will almost certainly also have a restore partition if it came with the OS that is currently installed. Try the Live disk for a while before installing it. As for safe boot? I find that disabling UEFI works best for me. Like pretty much all things Linux, it's more a question of what you want to do and how much effort you're willing to put into it. It's usually pretty easy.  Search engines help but you do need to know what to look for.

Comment: Pretty sure it has a 20gb restore partition or something like that. Would that work? Also, I'm going to use linux for python, js, and maybe a few video games, Playing on windows doesn't do well since I run 30fps, and I was wondering whether since Linux is more lightweight, whether it'd run better. Just a question.

Comment: @Jeremy, yes, the restore partition should have a copy of your default installation on it. You can also make a repair disk from the startup menu somewhere - I don't use Windows but I know it is there. Try using the Live USB or DVD and see where you go from there before making the choice to install it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @KGIII is uninstalling as simple as booting into the recovery drive and adding windows to the ubuntu drive? or what?

Comment: @Jeremy That will vary per computer. When booting up there's a hint on your screen. It's often something like "Press F12 to Repair your Computer" or something similar.